# The system cannot find the path specified for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys so I am new to everything including computers I don't know squat, nothing! I am recently trying to take ruby on rails on lynda.com. I have ran into many problems with using ruby and downloading rails I have followed allot of helpful tips which have helped but I cannot seem to get out of this loop for 6 hrs already. 
I am using `ruby 2.2.4 ,rails 2.4.5.1`  on the other hand I don't know how to use it and when I check

> rails -v

this pops up

> the system cannot find the path specified

I am using windows 10 by the way. So can someone please help in detail and hoping you have the patience to work with someone who knows nothing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to install ruby and rails on your windows 10 machine.

You can use [rails installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en) for installing ruby and all other stuff related to ruby and rails using a single installation.

Comment: Did that already but that still pops up and it only happens when I try to check on rails .

Comment: how do I do that? Would like to remind you I really know nothing here.

Comment: You can find the path variables at > My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System variables

Comment: And after this what do I look for? And what to do? Yes as you can see it did take some time for me to get here

Comment: Have you found the path for ruby has been configured there..?

Comment: Configure? Well it is there

Comment: Bala karthik finally got to show me the rails version I honestly don't know what I did watched a bunch of videos did a shit load of stuff then out of nowhere it works :-)